# Need this term simplified: $4n^2 \cdot 3n^4 - 5n^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone please describe to me the steps of solving the following equation which is covered under algebra (indices).

Please help with solving the following equation:

$$4n^2 \cdot 3n^4 - 5n^6.$$

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not even an equation. Your question doesn't belong here, it should be at least be on Math SE. Note that SE supports Math LaTeX.

Comment: This is not an equation but an expression. You do not solve expression but you can simplify them, factorize them, or apply various kinds of mathematical torture. Expressions are not a problem to be solve, but only a way of representing a mathematical entity, to say things very loosely.

Comment: And you don't solve expressions, you simplify them.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be clear, you can simplify this *expression*. (I.e., the expression is not an *equation*.)

$$\begin{align} 4n^2 \cdot 3n^4 - 5n^6 & = 4\cdot 3 \cdot n^2\cdot n^4 - 5n^6 \\ \\ & = 12 n^{2 + 4} - 5n^6 \\ \\ & =12 n^6 - 5 n^6 = (12 - 5)n^6 \\ \\ & = 7n^6\end{align}$$

Remark: Recall that $$a^n\cdot a^m = \underbrace{a\cdot a \cdots a}_{\large n\;\text{times}} \cdot \underbrace{a \cdot a \cdots a}_{\large m\;\text{times}} =  \underbrace{a \cdot a \cdot \cdots \cdot a}_{\large n + m\;\text{times}} = a^{n + m}$$

Comment: $\Large\overbrace{+}$

Comment: The groupings terms are very helpful! +1 (Guess what ...) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is basic algebra. When you multiply $4n^2$ by $3n^4$, you first multiply the constant terms (i.e. 4 and 3) to get 12.  Then, when you multiply the variable ($n$), you need to remember that you add the exponents. So, $n^2.n^4$ = $n^(2+4)$ = $n^6$.
So, the first part gives $12n^6$. Then we subtract the $5n^6$: $12n^6 - 5n^6 = 7n^6$.

Answer (score 0):

$$4n^2.3n^4=12n^6$$

Also $$12n^6 - 5n^6=7n^6$$

Comment: can you please explain how you got the answer?

Comment: $a^b.a^c=a^{b+c}$. anything else.